# How to use AllenNLP to implement a Decoder in seq2seq generation task?

Tags: nlp, pytorch, seq2seq, allennlp

I`m trying to realize a seq2seq generation style experiment, but i cannot find any instructions for implement a 'Decoder'.
I'm using the Newest Allennlp V2.1. So,I will appreciate it if you could give me some advice!

Answer (score 0):

Sample generation decoders can be found here: https://github.com/allenai/allennlp-models/tree/main/allennlp_models/generation/models